# Does H110 motherboard and i3 -6100 support VT-d/iommu mode?

Tags: virtual-machine, hardware-compatibility, vga-passtrough

I am trying to build a PC with H110 mobo and i3 - 6100. I want to run Ubuntu as host and Windows as a VM with Integrated Graphics pass through. While the Intel site mentions for VT-d support, I'm not sure whether my mobo will support it?

Comment: What's the specific motherboard?

Comment: @StephenKitt  Asus H110M-A (M.2)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same motherboard and I am struggling to configure GPU pass-thru to one VM hosted on my proxmox server.

This motherboard seems that it does not support IOMMU.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IOMMU-supporting_hardware#Gigabyte

Some bad news for us...